# Manual memory management explanation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management, reference-counting

I got this image from [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html):
[image]

Sorry for this stupid question. Someone can give an explanation of this image?. My interpretation:

1. We create an instance of an Object of class A.
2. After [[ClassA alloc]init] the object has a retain count of 1.
3. After this, we create an instance of ClassB and add him to Class A as an iVar ¿it is correct? Instantiation means a retain count of 1, and the relation of ownership (now A owns B) means an increment of 1 of the retain count. (1+1 = 2) Now B has a retain count of 2. ¿it is correct?  Anynone?

Comment: I believe the chart is talking about a single object created by Class A and used by Class B and Class C.

Comment: Makes sense. So you say, we create A, we add A to B as an iVar, then we copy C and add it to the B instance (that contains A), then we send a release method to A .... ¿it is correct?

Comment: No. An instance of A creates the object X. Then an instance of B retains an instance of the object X. Then an instance of C copies the object X.

Comment: It's pretty simple. Any method who's name begins with `alloc` or `new` or `copy` will return an object with a retain count of `1`. Any call to `retain` will increase the retain count by `1`, `release` will decrease the retain count by `1`, and `autorelease` will decrease the retain count next time the "current" pool is released (typically when the main thread is idle next). All other methods have no impact on the retain count at all — if they create an object it will be 1 but autoreleased to 0. If the retain count hits `0` the object may be destroyed (this is not guaranteed. do not rely on it)

Comment: With regard to ivars, if the `@property` definition defines it as `strong` or `retain` then the value will be retained when it's stored in the property and released when it's removed from the property. If it's `weak` or `assign` or `unsafe_unretained` then it will not be retained. If a property just has a `set` method but no `@property` definition you need to check the documentation but usually it will behave the same as `strong`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood the diagram. Going from left to right:

- An instance of Class A creates a new object - it has a retain count of one.
- An instance of Class B retains the new object - it now has a retain count of 2.
- An instance of class C makes a copy of the new object - this is another new object, with a retain count of one.
- The instance of Class A releases the new object - it now has a retain count of 1, so is not deallocated.
- Class C releases its copy - the copied instance is deallocated
- Class B releases its reference to the new object. The reference count returns to zero and it is deallocated.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! I will wait half an hour and I will accept your response.

Comment: I've updated it since I think Matteo's interpretation makes more sense, though the principles are the same.

Comment: Great ! Thans jrthurton, matteo and erkanyildiz. Now the explanation is crystal clear !

Answer (score 1):

*1) We create an instance of an Object of class A. `FALSE`*

**ClassA creates an instance of just another class, let's call it ClassZ.**

*2) After [[ClassA alloc]init] the object has a retain count of 1. `FALSE`*

**It is not [[ClassA alloc]init], it is [[ClassZ alloc]init]. Now the instance of ClassZ has retain count of 1.**

*3) After this, we create an instance of ClassB and add him to Class A as an iVar `FALSE`*

**An instance of ClassB just retains the instance of ClassZ created on step 1. And retain count of the instance of ClassZ becomes 2.**

*4) Instantiation means a retain count of 1, and the relation of ownership (now A owns B) means an increment of 1 of the retain count. (1+1 = 2) Now B has a retain count of 2. `FALSE`*

**Here it is not important who created ClassB and what its retain count at the moment. It is just another object claiming ownership on the instance of ClassZ.**

Answer (score 1):

So,
is really simple, follow this points whose explain the main line:

1- An instance of class **A allocs and initializes an object of class X** --> **X retain count = 1**;

2- An instance of class **B retain X**. It is not important how B obtain X. The important is that want have the ownership of the object to maintains it alive --> **X retain count = 2**;

3- **A release X** --> **X retain count = 1;**

4- **B release X** --> **X retain count = 0**; --> **X is deallocated**

The second part instead is just to explain that **copying an object, another object is allocated**, and so, **the same mechanism on this new object has not effects on the first object**.

Comment: This might make more sense than my interpretation actually. +1

Comment: Are you sure? An instance of class A cannot create an instance of X. Do you mean instead, "Inside a method of A, we create an object of class X, with [[X alloc] init];"  ?

Comment: It is what i wrote: A creates and allocs an instance of X, is not clear? i write better